# Группирования задач horizon

Tags: php, linux, laravel, supervisor

Использую `laravel horizon + supervisor`.

Появилась задача добавить данную связку для поддомена, создал еще один `supervisor` который следит уже за тем horizon`ом. В итоге заметил, что они выполняют задачи друг друга, т.е задачу с одного поддомена может выполниться на другом.

Вопрос: Как можно группировать эти задачи, чтобы каждые выполнялись в своей среде. Был вариант добавлять префиксы для `queue` но хотелось бы обойтись меньшей кровью

Comment: Кодовая база одна? Как организован проект? На одном сервере? Если на одном сервере, то подключаются к одной и той же БД redis?

Comment: Кодовая база разная, и подключаются к одной и той же бд редис

Comment: надо либо разные пространства в редисе использовать, либо префиксы. Но лучше на каждый проект своя БД

Comment: Только что попробовал и заработало, можете оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Важное правило любого проекта - **для каждого проекта своя БД** (mysql, redis, memcache, mongoDB, etc...).

В данном случае на разных проекта использовалась одна БД redis, в которой `Laravel Horizon` хранит информацию по своей работе.